# Dynamic iteration in r

Tags: r, iteration, subset

For a data table, how do I do a dynamic search and only select rows with the same Tail_No, same Flight_ID with different destinations. I have millions of rows
Below is the table I have

```
    My_data_table

   Unique_ID Tail_No  Flight_ID   Arrival_Airport 
    1AA       1234      abcd          JFK
    2AA       4234      bcde          BWI
    3AA       5234      zbcd          DCA
    4AA       6234      ybcd          LOS
    5AA       7234      mbcd          JFK
    6AA       1284      lbcd          LAX
    7AA       1234      abcd          DEN
```

This is the result I am looking for. Note I have millions of rows so subsetting by Tail_No and Flight_ID is not feasible.

```
     My Result_Table 
  Unique_ID  Tail_No  Flight_ID   Arrival_Airport 
    1AA       1234      abcd          JFK
    7AA       1234      abcd          DEN
```

Comment: @Mako212 - it's pretty clear to me. Only keep rows with a duplicated tail_no/flight_id that have different arrival_airport destinations

Answer (score 1):

First, remove all duplicates on Tail_No, Flight_ID and Arrival_Airport (destination). I.e. - those that are going to the same destination.
Then identify Tail_No / Flight_ID combinations that are still duplicated.
Finally, merge back to the original set to get the requested rows:

```
vars <- c("Tail_No", "Flight_ID")
tmp <- dat[!duplicated(dat[c(vars, "Arrival_Airport")]),]
merge(tmp, tmp[duplicated(dat[vars]), vars])

#  Tail_No Flight_ID Unique_ID Arrival_Airport
#1    1234      abcd       1AA             JFK
#2    1234      abcd       7AA             DEN
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading on how subsetting [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/subsetting-data/). This snippet should do what you're looking for.

```
My_data_table[My_data_table$Flight_ID == 'abcd' & My_data_table$Tail_No == 1234,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Second attempt: Subset to rows where we have duplicate Tail_No/Flight_ID pairs, then filter to unique Arrival_Airport within each group

```
require(data.table)
setDT(My_data_table)

My_data_table[,if(.N>1)unique(.SD),keyby=.(Tail_No,Flight_ID)]

   Tail_No Flight_ID Unique_ID Arrival_Airport
1:    1234      abcd       1AA             JFK
2:    1234      abcd       7AA             DEN
```

Comment: @user8192069 Sorry, copy and paste fail (I think), try it again!